# How to increase the height of DevExpress ComboBox droplist

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I am displaying a combo box with facilities. There are a large number of facilities overall.
I would like to show a larger group of them. Currently the combo box only has about 10 and then the user has to scroll for more. How can I show the combo box as a larger group at the first?

```
<td>
   <div>
      <dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel4" runat="server" Text="Facility:">
      </dx:ASPxLabel>
      <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="cbFacility" runat="server" ValueType="System.String" 
         Width="300px" EnableViewState="true"  
         onselectedindexchanged="cbFacility_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" >
      </dx:ASPxComboBox>
   </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can we see some examples of the values being inserted into the combo box, or the code to populate this control?

Comment: What control set/library is `<dx:*>`?

Comment: SpikeX, it's DevExpress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the ASPxComboBox.DropDownRows property to something larger than 10?

See this Q&A over at DevExpress http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q353996

From the answer

> ...you can manage the drop-down window height by using either the
>   ASPxComboBox.DropDownHeight or ASPxComboBox.DropDownRows property.

Answer (score 2):

You could specify the value of DropDownRows as described [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemComboBox_DropDownRowstopic). When in doubt check the docs :P